# Error when trying to install SignalR package using nuget

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, signalr

I want to install SignalR using (Add Library Package Reference). I can search and find it (`Microsoft.aspnet.signalr`). When I click on install this errors appear:

> Id is required.
>
> version is required.
>
> authors is required.
>
> Description is required.

What I have to do?

Comment: can you give more detail?

Comment: I have created a new web application and in console :PM> install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 1.1.2)' not installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source...
Done
Install-Package : Id is required.
Version is required.
Authors is required.
Description is required.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet